# Find all strings (non-lower-ASCII) beginning with a prefix in an ordered STL container

Tags: c++, string, stl, binary-search, non-ascii-characters

I have a huge STL container of `std::string` (hundreds of thousands of entries). I am using a `vector` at the moment, but I am happy to change. The contents are sorted alphabetically, and are formed of alphabetical lower case characters a-z *plus* `ñ`.

I am trying to implement a function which receives a `const std::string& prefix` and returns a pair of iterators, one pointing at the first element beginning with such prefix and the other one pointing at the last one. If no strings match the criteria, return any two identical iterators. I need efficiency in the lookup because the vector is huge, so I want to make use of it being ordered for a binary search.

I think `std::lower_bound` is what I am looking for, but I am missing a function to compare `std::string`s which can deal with the Spanish `ñ`.

Comment: Are you using UTF-8?  As long as you use the same encoding in your search prefix string as you use in the vector, you should be fine.  For speed, you can capture the prefix length into the lambda and call the appropriate overload of `std::string::compare`.

Comment: You can write a custom compare function to pass to `lower_bound()`, but any comparison you perform will have to take charset/locale into account since `ñ` is not ASCII. `std::string` only knows about `char` values and has no concept of charset/locale, so you need to handle it manually. `ñ` can be a different `char` value in different charsets, and it does not exist at all in some charsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to look up words by prefix, the correct structure is a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). You can take a public implementation (there are several on the internet) and extend it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the whole range of equal values with [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range). It'll give you a pair of iterators, one to the beginning and one past the end of the range, if there is at least one matching string in the collection. If the string is not present, it will give two equal iterators to the first spot immediately after the position that string would belong if it were present.

Given that you only care about finding an identical substring, a normal string comparison (of the first N characters) should work fine. If you wanted to support (for example) things like a pair of input strings, and find all inputs between them, so you needed to search from (say) "m*" to "o*" (with your "ñ*" strings treated as coming between the two) then you'd have to get a little fancier (the usual then is to build a collation table with the character code as the index, and the relative order as the value at each position).

Comment: Can you do prefix matching with the default `equal_range()`, or is it a full-length comparison only? Or do you need a custom compare functor to implement prefix matching?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: you can pass a comparison object that does whatever sort of comparison you specify. In this case you'd pass one that (for example) does a comparison like `return a.substr(0, N) < b.substr(0, N);`.

Comment: I would probably use one of the `std::string::compare()` overloads instead to avoid unnecessary allocations, such as `return (a.compare(0, b.size(), b) == 0);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In reality, I probably would too--but I can never remember its parameters without looking them up, so I was lazy for the moment...